# Reading data from European DTCO company card

Tags: security, cryptography, smartcard

I need to be able to read card and company identification data from European digital tachograph company cards (smart cards). These are described within the document [COMMISSION REGULATION (EC) No 1360/2002](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ%3aL:2002:207:0001:0252%3aEN%3aPDF) but I have run into a problem. The data I need to be able to read is contained within the file **EF Identification**, which must be read with secure messaging and I therefore need to issue a **Manage Secure Environment** APDU command that requires a key identifier that identifies a key residing on the card.

I don't know where to find these key identifiers or the data that makes them up (described in an appendix of the document). I am waiting for feedback from our partners in Europe but thought I would take a chance an ask here in the hope that someone will have done this and be able to offer some advice.

The key identifier is made up of an equipment serial number, a date, a manufacturer code and a manufacturer specific type. This suggests a problem as I need to be able to access the data from any company card, regardless of manufacturer, issuer or holder. Not sure how I can get the data to compose the key.

I realise that this is pretty specialised information but have been stalled for over a week so am pretty desperate to find a solution so I can continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you first have to obtain a certificate from a country CA. You can then perform the following algorithm (simplified from Appendix 11, section 4):

1. Select and read the card certificate (EF_CERTIFICATE)
2. Issue a Manage Security Environment command to select the Root CA public key
3. Issue a Verify Certificate with the country CA certificate
4. Issue a Manage Security Environment command to select the country CA public key
5. Issue a Verify Certificate with your certificate
6. Issue a Manage Security Environment command to select your public key
7. Issue an Internal authenticate command. Verify response.
8. Issue a Get Challenge command
9. Issue an External authenticate command
10. Calculate the session key
11. Select File EF_IDENTIFICATION
12. Perform a Read Binary command using secure messaging (you need the session key to calculate the checksum and decrypt the result).

Comment: Thank you for your help but it turns out, and we learned this only yesterday, that we have no need to do any of this. The application we have been commissioned to replace does not access the secure information on the card but uses an open non-application-related serial number (cardExtendedSerialNumber from EF ICC) to identify which card is in which reader and uses this with the user-entered application-specific card number to create a table that can be used to address the reader containing a specific card. We have been told to simply do the same.

Comment: @Steve: Ah, much simpler. Thank you for posting a follow-up.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the standard, but I would assume that you read out `EF Card_Certificate`, recover the certificate content and extract the key identifier from that.

Assuming you have the root certificate (it is published here: http://dtc.jrc.it/erca_of_doc/EC_PK.zip), you will need to:

1. Read EF CA_Certificate
2. Follow the algorithm in Appendix 11, section 3.3.3
3. Extract the CA public key from the certificate content
4. Read EF Card_Certificate
5. Follow the algorithm in Appendix 11, section 3.3.3
6. The Key Identifier should now be byte 20-27 of the recovered certificate content.

Comment: I wondered if that would be possible. I can already read the Card_Certificate and I'll dig through the specification and see if it contains the identifier I need.

Comment: @Steve Crane: I skimmed through the standard and added a few more pointers.

Comment: Thank you, this is most helpful. Trying to follow that standard is not too easy if you aren't familiar with working with smart cards, keys and certificates.

Comment: Making some progress but still struggling a little. When you said "Assuming you have the root certificate", does this mean we need to have a certificate from somewhere other than the card in order to complete the authentication process? I don't have such a certificate. How do you get one? As we are writing an application that needs one, do we need to request that some authority issue us with one?

Comment: @Steve Crane: I believe the root certificate is the one published by ECRA.

Comment: Thanks, found it on the [European Commission - Digital Tachograph website](http://dtc.jrc.it).

Comment: Despite all the advice you have given I'm still struggling with this. I don't have enough understanding of the cryptographic code needed to follow the algorithm in Appendix 11, section 3.3.3. Most of the steps are simply retrieving segments of byte arrays and I can do that. The steps I can't work out how to do are, **open Sign with CA Public Key: Sr¡ = X.CA.PK [Sign]** and **check Hash(C¡) = H¡**. How to **open Sign** and **compute Hash**? The only colleague of mine with experience in this area doesn't know; says the document is confusing and worded strangely. I'm almost ready to give up!

Comment: For days now I have been Googling for sample code and trying to apply it but am at a loss. Nothing I try seems to work, undoubtedly because I don't fully understand it.

Comment: @Steve: It means use the CA public key to perform a raw RSA encryption of `Sign` (the first 128 bytes of X.C). Later calculate the SHA-1 hash of the full certificate and verify that it matches the H' extracted from the result of the decryption. If you need more help, I think you should make a new question (remember to note which programming language you are using). If you make a comment about the new question here, I will be sure to try to help.

Comment: @Steve: Ah, you already made a new question. I will take a look unless it has already been answered.

Comment: @Steve: I have made another better answer. I will wait a bit then delete this one.